# Sort of "\let" for Tikz shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to redefine the name of a Tikz object in case of name conflict, like the `\let` command for a TeX macro?

As practical case, I have define a set of path decoration that can simply be used as:

```
\draw[pneumatic signal] (A) -- (B);
```

I have named one of these decoration *signal* for an undefined signal type. But this badly chosen name is conflicting with the signal shape of the shapes.symbols library.

So, do I need to rename my decoration or is there a mean to change a name as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not wise to redefine the existing styles as other constructions, styles etc. might depend on it. As is for the TeX macros with `\let`, you are at risk of breaking things. But technically the last definition wins over the prior definitions.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[circle/.style={red}]
  \node[draw, circle, xshift=2cm](a){A};
  \node[draw, circle, minimum width=2cm, yshift=-2cm](b){B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]